# In Neo4J return root nodes when having two types of relationships

Tags: neo4j

I have a one direction tree as described as:

Node_C [is_a_method_of] Node_A

Node_D [is_related_to] Node_B

Node_C [is_related_to] Node_D

Node_A and Node_B are root nodes because they are not related or are a method of other nodes. How can I return them?

I saw in another post:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)--()
RETURN n;
```

But that returns orphan nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably want to add some relationship type and direction to your query:

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NOT (n)-[:is_a_method_of]->() AND NOT (n)-[:is_related_to]->()
RETURN n;
```

You haven't really specified the direction of relationships in your graph, so this is only my assumption. You could adapt this query to work on your graph schema if my assumptions are wrong.